# Using Google Cloud datastore, Chinese characters displays correctly in console, but not when I read it from datastore

Tags: utf-8, google-cloud-datastore

I am using google cloud datastore to save some text in Chinese, I can view these text correctly in console, but when I read it from datastore and pass it back to my android app, it become non-readable nonsense.

```
    val entity = try {
        val key = KeyFactory.createKey(Records.KIND, "keyname")
        datastore.get(key)
    } catch (e: Throwable) { null }

    val text = if (entity != null) {
         entity.getProperty("name") as String
    } else ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I forgot to set characterEncoding for HttpServletResponse, that is why I get non readable text.

I just put "characterEncoding = "UTF-8"", and problem solved.